# SharePoint Classic UI Web Part Page Field Filter error: Not all property values could be saved: An error occurred

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, classic-experience

I want to add a page field filter web part to a docsethomepage.aspx of a document set content type. It doesn't let me fill out the greyed out property "Choose Column from list where the current page is stored" (freely translated from German). It says that this property is mandatory. How can I set this property? I try to achieve a connection to two other web parts that connect via an ID column in the document set.

[image]